# How to traverse the PDOStatement object i.e. fetch first, last previous next etc?

Tags: php, object, resultset, reusability, pdo

I am trying to access data again and again in a webpage. Is there a better way ? some thing like movetofirst(), movetolast(), movetoprevious(), movetonext() could be nice.

right now i am retrieving the resultset as an array (using fetchall()) and resusing the array again and again.

Is there something like below be done? I need not execute the query again and again. keep the data in a array and consume resources if the result/array is of many hundred rows.

```
$sql = 'SELECT cityname, statename FROM TBLPLACES ORDER BY cityname, statename';
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
if ($stmt) {
    while($row=$stmt->fetch()){
       // do some thing
    }

    // do some more thing
    //
    // now here, can i access same $stmt object
    // to fetch resultset again without executing
    // $stmt = $conn->query($sql); again ?
    // (no change in query sql, need to fetch the same static data again.)
    //
    // something like below will be nice.
    //
    // $stmt->movetofirst();
    // while($row=$stmt->fetch()){
    //   do some thing;
    // } 
}
```

Comment: What's exactly preventing you from creating such methods? You know what you want, you know what the methods must do, you have the data in the array, you know the size of the array.. where's the problem? First, next, previous, last - it's all just offseting the array whose size you know.

Comment: can't you just store the results in an array and use it for the next times you need that data?

Comment: hi n.b, phihag and mishu, ofcourse, with array i can traverse as many times as i wish in any sequence. if the query results in thousands of rows, then i need a huge array (i.e memory space) which i want to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch last result you can do:

`$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST);`

Or write the row numbers manualy. Other `PDO::FETCH_ORI_*` constants [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php), but essentially you want to pay more attention to the 2nd and 3rd parameter in [PDOStatement::fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to get the whole result in an array:

```
$sql = 'SELECT cityname, statename FROM TBLPLACES ORDER BY cityname, statename';
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
// You should not silently ignore errors.
// Set PDO error mode to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION to handle query failure
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($data as $row) {
  // Do one thing
}
foreach ($data as $row) {
  // Do another thing
}
```

Comment: hi, i think it's best to show how to access the properties also in ``forEach ``

Answer (score 0):

with PDO you don't need to create a query to get previous or next,
try juste :   `PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL`

reference (example 2):
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php